# mex file for calling dgesv LAPACK routine

Tags: matlab

Although I've read Mathworks documentation, I find it very difficult to construct a mex-file which calls dgesv LAPACK routine. Could someone please give me a hand? I'm ok in matlab and a beginner in C, so I can't work this out.

I have a code that I can play with, but I don't have a clue on how to proceed.

```
#include "mex.h"
// Include headers for your library

void mexFunction(int nlhs,mxArray *plhs[],int nrhs,const mxArray *prhs[])
{
   void* x = mxGetData(prhs[0]); // Assume one input. Check nrhs
   plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(10,10,mxREAL); // Create 10x10 double matrix for output
   void* y = mxGetData(plhs[0]);
   yourLibraryFunction(x, y); // Read from x and write to y. Pass sizes in if needed
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not expert but I will try to explain you. See this example from mathworks.

The parameter prhs has the input arguments (that there are nrhs of them) and the plhs has the output arguments (that there are nlhs) of them.

First you have to "transform" your parameters in types that you can use them from C. The parameters in C are pointers to the matrix so we use mxGetPr to the data. In documentation says that return a pointer to the first element of the real data and in C the name of array is a pointer at the first element.

Then with mxGetM and mxGetN you get the dimensions of matrix A and vector b and at bnrhs you save the number of columns of the matrix b because you need to pass it as the second argument at the dgesv. But, because you work in C and you have pointers to the real data (usually in function we don't want to use pointer to the real data) you have to copy the matrices and in C if you want to copy an array you have to do it element by element because if you do AT = A they point at the same position. In mex files we use mxCalloc instead of malloc.

Then you have to call the dgesv function and last you have to return the result by making the pointer plhs[0] to point at the vector that dgesv return you as solution.

```
/*=========================================================
* dgesv.c
* example for illustrating how to use LAPACK within a C
* MEX-file on HP700, IBM_RS and PC.  
*
*  Solves the symmetric indefinite system of linear 
* equations A*X=B for X.
* X = dgesv(A,B) computes LU decomposition of A and returns 
* the result X such that A*X is B. 
* B must have as many rows as A. A is n-by-n matrix and b is n-by-bnrsh matrix
* http://www.netlib.org/lapack/double/dgesv.f
* This is a MEX-file for MATLAB.
*
* Compiling command in Matlab
* mex -v -g dgesv.c <matlab>\extern\examples\refbook\fort.c -I<matlab>\extern\examples\refbook <matlab>\extern\lib\win32\microsoft\msvc60\libmwlapack.lib
*=======================================================*/
#include "mex.h"
#include "c:\\matlab6p5\\extern\\examples\\refbook\\fort.h"

void mexFunction( int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[] )
{

   /* mex interface to LAPACK functions dsysvx and zhesvx */

   int m, n, bnrhs, lda, *ipiv, ldb, info;
   double *A,*b, *AT, *bT, *ret;
   int i;

   if (nrhs != 2) {
     mexErrMsgTxt("Expect 2 input arguments and return 1 output argument");
   }

   A = mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
   b = mxGetPr(prhs[1]);
   m = mxGetM(prhs[0]);
   n = mxGetN(prhs[0]); 
   bnrhs = mxGetN(prhs[1]);

   AT = (double *)mxCalloc(m*n,sizeof(double));
   bT = (double *)mxCalloc(m*bnrhs,sizeof(double));
   ipiv = (int *)mxCalloc(m,sizeof(int));

   for(i=0;i<m*bnrhs;i++) {
       bT[i] = b[i];
   }
   mexPrintf("\n");
   for(i=0;i<m*n;i++) AT[i] = A[i];
   lda = m;
   ldb = m;
   dgesv(&m, &bnrhs, AT, &lda, ipiv, bT, &ldb, &info);      

   for(i=0;i<m;i++) {
       mexPrintf("%f\t",bT[i]);
   }

   plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(m,bnrhs,mxREAL);
   ret = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);
   for(i=0;i<m*bnrhs;i++) ret[i] = bT[i];

   mxFree(AT);
   mxFree(bT);
   mxFree(ipiv);
}
```

source: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fx_files/8006/1/dgesv.c http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/mex-library.html